# LightDM says "Password Incorrect" sometime while it isn't

Tags: debian, lightdm

Sometimes I can't login with LightDM (with it's GTK greeter), because it says "Password Incorrect", while I've typed correctly. When that happens, I need to login at TTY1 and restart the LightDM service. How can I make it always working?

Comment: Check with `localectl status` if the correct keyboard-layout is set, when you can't log in.

Comment: @Bahamut: But I can type my username correctly, so that couldn't be it…

Comment: I had simliar Problems under trusty lightdm keyboard-lay-out was sometimes en, but I'm from germany. In my Password was a y so it was only relevant to my password not my username.  Another long shot.  When it happends as root or `sudo journalctl -b -u lightdm`